# Objective-C: How to put boolean values in JSON dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, json, macos

I could not find out how to insert a boolean value (to appear as `key:true` in the JSON string) in my NSDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary* jsonDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[jsonDict setValue: YES forKey: @"key"];
```

The code above does not run (obviously because YES is not an object).
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You insert booleans into a dictionary using `NSNumber`. In this case, you can use the literal expression `@YES` directly, together with a dictionary literal, to make this a one-liner:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{@"key" : @YES};
```

To encode it to JSON, use `+[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error]`:

```
NSError *serializationError;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                    dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict
                    options:0 error:&serializationError];
if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"%s: error serializing to JSON: object %@ - error %@",
          __func__, jsonDict, serializationError];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it answer the problem above. JSON format is different from NSDictionary because of how a boolean is represented. What would you do if there are many platform that are sending data in JSON format and you want all of them to have the same representation (key:true)?

Answer (score 8):

+[NSNumber numberWithBool:] is the typical way to add a boolean to a NSDictionary.

Answer (score 6):

With Objective-C literals, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] can be represented with just @YES,

You can create your dictionary like so:

```
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = @{@"key":@YES};
```